# How do I fix panic occurred error after installing dual-boot Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Win 7?

Tags: 12.04, windows, dual-boot, lts

I first attempted to install Ubuntu on my USB drive.  That worked just fine, but for reasons that weren't obvious to me then, it worked unbearably slow.

So I instead attempted to install Ubuntu alongside my Win 7 install.  I used the "install alongside..." option, and it seemed to work well until the reboot occurred, and my computer would automatically load Windows.  Grub just didn't want to start.  Keep in mind I allocated 20GB to Ubuntu during this attempt, and I didn't have my internet connected.

I cleared the Ubuntu partition and joined it back to the partition that holds Win 7 (by extending the Win 7 partition), and simply attempted another install.  I followed the same steps as last time, only I allocated 50GB to Ubuntu, and I had my internet connected.  The install took all night long.  I had to leave my system on overnight and cross my fingers that it would work.  It especially took forever when downloading language packages.

Now Grub loads.  It gives me a number of options (I don't have the Grub screen in front of me so please forgive me for paraphrasing the options):
1. Boot Linux on Ubuntu normally.
2. Boot Linux on Ubuntu in recovery mode.
3. Run CheckDisk.
4. Another option that involves CheckDisk.
5. Boot Windows 7 on sda1.
6. Boot Windows 7 on sda2.

Whenever I choose option 1, I get a terminal screen that flashes a bunch of processes on the screen and ends with "panic occurred. rebooting in 30 seconds."  This happens every time.

I chose option 2, and within recovery mode I attempted to repair.  The repair process attempted to download files and each attempt failed.  I then attempted to enable networking within recovery mode, and it just flashed a bunch of processes and, without saying panic occurred, said "rebooting in 30 seconds" and rebooted.

I haven't tried either CheckDisk or MemCheck options (now that I think of it I think it does say MemCheck instead of CheckDisk).

Choosing option 5 boots Windows 7 normally with no problems (so far).

Choosing option 6 starts Windows 7, but then reboots my computer.

Is there any way I can repair Ubuntu without having to wipe its partition and start again from scratch?  The installation process took quite a long time to complete and I'd rather there be (if there is any) a more simpler process of getting Ubuntu to work on my system alongside Win 7.

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE:**  I reinstalled on the 50GB partition without connecting to the internet, and I'm getting the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tray 2 re-Install ubuntu from licve into the 50gb partition without a internet connection, on rebbot made the connection ON and update yuor system.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be taking too long to install ubuntu. At most 30 mins. Try [the procedure used here](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/), It works because I just did it. I think it's better to re-install it than trying to fix it.

Instead of using the "install Ubuntu alongside my Win 7," select "something else."